# Data frame R - Reduce to exclude certain rows based on text combination

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame and I am trying to exclude certain rows based on the string. I try to run reduce with grepl but that gives me true/false. I could use the additional column to reduce my data frame but I wonder if I can do at the same time when I look for string?

**My data frame**

```
A <- c('A','B','C hello','C','C hello','C hello')
B <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

df <- data.frame(A,B)

df$Hello<- Reduce(`&`, lapply(c('C', '^((?!Hello).)*$'), grepl, df$A , perl = T, ignore.case = T))
```

Result I get is:

```
A          B    Hello
A          1    FALSE
B          2    FALSE
C hello    3    FALSE
C          4    TRUE
C hello    5    FALSE
C hello    6    FALSE
```

I want to have just row when C is in the string and hello is not.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the start (`^`) and `$` to get the `TRUE` value as showed in the 'Hello' column

```
grepl("^C$", df$A)
```

Comment: Is Kalenji after `df[grepl("^C$", df$A),]`?

Comment: @LukeC  It could be the end goal, but I think here they want to replicate the 'Hello' column

Comment: Hi All, All I want i just this row `C          4` as the data frame df with rest being excluded.

Comment: so I have the following codes but I try to do it with one line? `df <- df[grepl("C", df$A),]
df <- df[!grepl("hello", df$A),]`

Comment: @Kalenji  Wouldn't the `grepl("^C$", df$A)` gets you the expected index